# Identityserver 4 Protecting an Api with user identity tokens

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, identityserver4

I currently have an identity server 4 instance running on my local pc. I have followed the examples (http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/quickstarts/1_client_credentials.html#calling-the-api) and have my MVC 5 client set up to redirect to IdentityServer 4. It is working with the Azure Active Directory. I added custom scopes and claims for the MVC 5 client so that MVC 5 client checks the user claims to see if they have permission to perform an action or see a piece of the UI.

I want my MVC 5 client to talk to a Web API. I know this can be done using the client auth flow by passing client + secret (http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/grant_types.html#interactive-clients). However I would like to still protect the API by user claims and not the client claims.

I'm not sure if what I am doing is classified as an interactive client (http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/grant_types.html#interactive-clients).

I'm finding googling for resources hard, because I'm not sure if there is a name for the flow (if it exists). Any help or reference documents would be great!

How would I call Identity Server 4 for a token to access the API from the MVC 5 client on behave of the user?

Comment: Claims are not necessarily for protection. Please read this [article](https://leastprivilege.com/2016/12/16/identity-vs-permissions/).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I will investigate more. From my short investigation it doesn't seem that there is an industry protocol for handling permissions. Definitely something I need to investigate more. Thanks again

Comment: I don't know if you've noticed the [PocliyServer](https://policyserver.io/). That's the follow up of the article. Do take a look at the source code of the [free open source](https://github.com/policyserver/policyserver.local) version.